# How to display products in expiry date ending before one month in Magento programmatically?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I have created an expiry_date attribute in admin. I have chosen expiry date some products 31-12-2017.My requirement is expiry date ending before one month(30-11-2017) products display.I don't know how to implement this task.Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your product collection

```
$currentDate = Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d');
$plusOneMonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($currentDate . "+1 months"));

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('expiry_date', array('from' => $currentDate, 'to' => $plusOneMonth));
```

Comment: Hi @ Dinesh Yadav, Thank you. Where this code added.Please tell me file path?.

Comment: Where you want to show your products? Do you want to implement this filter on category page?

Comment: My requirement is to display products expiry date ending before one month. I have a display that products in table format through programmatically.Can you please help me?

Comment: I have to save the file into Magento root folder .Show my products in the frontend.Can you please help me?

Comment: I want to display on the table, Product name,sku, Expiry date in the front end.Can you please help me?

Comment: Where do you exactly want to show these products on the frontend?  I mean to say, do you want to show this on a homepage or any CMS page?

Comment: how to export and display products which are going to expire in Magento admin panel reports tab?

Comment: how to export and display products which are going to expire in Magento admin panel reports tab? find below screen my requirement https://prnt.sc/hh45kw

Comment: Hi@ Dinesh Yadav, Do you have any idea this task.Can you please help me?

Comment: I have created a module here https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/204056/48571   check this.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a very old question but we also had a similar requirement because we sell supplement products with expiry date. We searched online and found the following extension which helped us -:

[Magento 2 Product Shelf Life](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-2-product-shelf-life.html)

Hope it helps you or other store owners who sell products with limited shelf life or expiry date