# How to export and display products which are going to expire in Magento admin panel reports tab?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

How can I export and display products which are going to expire in the Magento admin panel reports tab?

Below is a screen shot with my requirement.

[image: Desired menu item]

Answer (score 0):

I have created a module for you. Try this

> app/etc/modules/Dinesh_Expiredproducts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Dinesh_Expiredproducts>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Dinesh_Expiredproducts>
  </modules>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Dinesh/Expiredproducts/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Dinesh_Expiredproducts>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Dinesh_Expiredproducts>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <expiredproducts>
        <class>Dinesh_Expiredproducts_Helper</class>
      </expiredproducts>
    </helpers>
    <blocks>
      <expiredproducts>
        <class>Dinesh_Expiredproducts_Block</class>
      </expiredproducts>
    </blocks>
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <expiredproducts>
        <use>admin</use>
        <args>
          <module>Dinesh_Expiredproducts</module>
          <frontName>admin_expiredproducts</frontName>
        </args>
      </expiredproducts>
    </routers>
  </admin>
  <adminhtml>
    <menu>
      <report module="reports">
        <children>
          <products module="reports">
            <children>
              <expiredproducts module="reports">
                <title>Expiredproducts</title>
                <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                <action>admin_expiredproducts/adminhtml_expiredproducts</action>
              </expiredproducts>
            </children>
          </products>
        </children>
      </report>
    </menu>
    <acl>
      <resources>
        <all>
          <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>
          <children>
            <expiredproducts translate="title" module="expiredproducts">
              <title>Expiredproducts</title>
              <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
              <children>
          <expiredproducts translate="title">
            <title>Manage Expiredproducts</title>
            <sort_order>0</sort_order>
          </expiredproducts>
              </children>
            </expiredproducts>
          </children>
        </admin>
      </resources>
    </acl>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <expiredproducts>
          <file>expiredproducts.xml</file>
        </expiredproducts>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Dinesh/Expiredproducts/Block/Adminhtml/Expiredproducts.php

```
<?php


class Dinesh_Expiredproducts_Block_Adminhtml_Expiredproducts extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container{

    public function __construct()
    {

    $this->_controller = "adminhtml_expiredproducts";
    $this->_blockGroup = "expiredproducts";
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper("expiredproducts")->__("Expiredproducts Manager");
    $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper("expiredproducts")->__("Add New Item");
    parent::__construct();
    $this->_removeButton('add');
    }

}
```

> app/code/local/Dinesh/Expiredproducts/Block/Adminhtml/Expiredproducts/Grid.php

```
<?php

class Dinesh_Expiredproducts_Block_Adminhtml_Expiredproducts_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid
{

        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->setId("expiredproductsGrid");
                $this->setDefaultSort("entity_id");
                $this->setDefaultDir("DESC");
                $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        }

        protected function _prepareCollection()
        {
               $currentDate = Mage::getModel('core/date')->gmtDate('Y-m-d');
               $plusOneMonth = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($currentDate . "+1 months"));

               $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
               $collection->addAttributeToSelect("name")->addFieldToFilter('expiry_date', array('from' => $currentDate, 'to' => $plusOneMonth));

                $this->setCollection($collection);
                return parent::_prepareCollection();
        }
        protected function _prepareColumns()
        {
                $this->addColumn("entity_id", array(
                "header" => Mage::helper("expiredproducts")->__("ID"),
                "align" =>"right",
                "width" => "50px",
                "type" => "number",
                "index" => "entity_id",
                ));

                $this->addColumn("name", array(
                "header" => Mage::helper("expiredproducts")->__("Name"),
                "index" => "name",
                ));
                $this->addColumn("sku", array(
                "header" => Mage::helper("expiredproducts")->__("SKU"),
                "index" => "sku",
                ));
            $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV')); 
            $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel'));

                return parent::_prepareColumns();
        }

        public function getRowUrl($row)
        {
               return '#';
        }



        protected function _prepareMassaction()
        {
            $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('entity_ids');
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(true);
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('remove_expiredproducts', array(
                     'label'=> Mage::helper('expiredproducts')->__('Remove Expiredproducts'),
                     'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/adminhtml_expiredproducts/massRemove'),
                     'confirm' => Mage::helper('expiredproducts')->__('Are you sure?')
                ));
            return $this;
        }


}
```

> app/code/local/Dinesh/Expiredproducts/Adminhtml/ExpiredproductsController.php

```
<?php

class Dinesh_Expiredproducts_Adminhtml_ExpiredproductsController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
        protected function _isAllowed()
        {
        //return Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('expiredproducts/expiredproducts');
            return true;
        }

        protected function _initAction()
        {
                $this->loadLayout()->_setActiveMenu("expiredproducts/expiredproducts")->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Expiredproducts  Manager"),Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Expiredproducts Manager"));
                return $this;
        }
        public function indexAction() 
        {
                $this->_title($this->__("Expiredproducts"));
                $this->_title($this->__("Manager Expiredproducts"));

                $this->_initAction();
                $this->renderLayout();
        }

        /**
         * Export order grid to CSV format
         */
        public function exportCsvAction()
        {
            $fileName   = 'expiredproducts.csv';
            $grid       = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('expiredproducts/adminhtml_expiredproducts_grid');
            $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getCsvFile());
        } 
        /**
         *  Export order grid to Excel XML format
         */
        public function exportExcelAction()
        {
            $fileName   = 'expiredproducts.xml';
            $grid       = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('expiredproducts/adminhtml_expiredproducts_grid');
            $this->_prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $grid->getExcelFile($fileName));
        }
}
```

> app/code/local/Dinesh/Expiredproducts/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class Dinesh_Expiredproducts_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

> app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/expiredproducts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
  <expiredproducts_adminhtml_expiredproducts_index>
    <reference name="content">
      <block type="expiredproducts/adminhtml_expiredproducts" name="expiredproducts" />
    </reference>
  </expiredproducts_adminhtml_expiredproducts_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: Hi @ Dinesh Yadav, I have followed your instructions but it shows error. I have to go to Admin->Reports->products->expired products click it shows 404 error.How to fix these error? Can you please help me? Please find my screenshots.https://prnt.sc/hirdqh this link is admin below link is an error.https://prnt.sc/hirbvd

Comment: There might be an issue in your controller action.

Comment: Which file I am missed controller function.Can you please tell me?

Comment: My site URL shows this link http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/admin_expiredproducts/adminhtml_expiredproducts/index/key/6ae9450ac85771e73887bef0a756c93c/

Comment: I have changed to this path app/code/local/Dinesh/Expired products/Adminhtml/ExpiredproductsController.php to app/code localDinesh/Expired products/controllers/Adminhtml/ExpiredproductsController.php after I have click expired products options it shows below screenshot.https://prnt.sc/hirtcy.Can you please help what I am missing

Comment: Hi @ Dinesh Yadav, Thank you very much it is working.But I have one requirement days(expiry_date attribute remaining days) displayed. I will try it is not working.Is it possible to days(expifunctionry_date attribute remaining days)_preparecoloumns  function in grid.php.Can you please help me? please check my screenshot?https://prnt.sc/hiw4ud

Comment: Do you want to show expiry_date attribute in grid? Is it what you require?

Comment: I want to display how many days to be expire in another column

Comment: Hi @Dinesh Yadav, 
I want to display how many days to expire in another column.Can you please help me?

Comment: Hi  @ Dinesh Yadav, I need your help .you  have developed the module for expired products so I have one requirement, my requirement is I need to add drop down box beside Export to based under drop down we need to select months result should be based on selected months.Can you please check my screenshot.https://prnt.sc/hjpx9a Can you please help me?

Comment: Hi @ Dinesh Yadav, I need your help? The below screenshot is my requirement?  https://prnt.sc/hkn41c   Can you please help me?

Comment: I am busy nowadays. I have never done this before. I have to check it.

Comment: Hi@ Dinesh Yadav, I need your help.how to add selected months in drop down box in expired products admin grid.Is it possible?.Can you please help me? Please find the screenshot that is my requirement?  https://prnt.sc/hkn41c

Comment: Hi @ Dinesh Yadav, I need your help.Can you please help me?